# How to approach to fitting curve?

Tags: approximation, algebraic-curves, curves

I'd like to approximate fitting curve some kind of curves like below.
(1, 3.5), (2, 4.3), (3, 7.2), (4, 8) which is having 4 points.

[image]

and I heard that this solver is PINV() of matlab function.
But I don't know how to use.

Would you please let me know how to use and find a approximation fitting curve equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a polynomial fit, you can use the function polyfit. In your case you would use

```
x=1:4;y=[3.5,4.3,7.2,8];c=polyfit(x,y,d)
```

where d is the degree of the desired polynomial (where $d \in \{ 0,1,\dots,n-1 \}$ and $n$ is the number of data points). polyfit then gives the coefficients $a_d,a_{d-1},\dots,a_0$ of the polynomial $a_d x^d + \dots + a_0$, in that order. So if you had d=2 and a desired evaluation point x0, then you could evaluate this way:

```
y0=c(1)*x0^2+c(2)*x0+c(3)
```

There are at least two better ways to do it (Horner's method is one; a vectorized version of the above is another), but it's fine to do it the simple way in a small case like this.

More generally, suppose you have a model of the form $y=\sum_{j=1}^n c_j f_j(x)$ for known functions $f_j$ and unknown coefficients $c_j$, and data points $(x_1,y_1),\dots,(x_n,y_n)$. Then you can assemble the (usually overdetermined) linear system which is given by $y_i=\sum_{j=1}^n c_j f_j(x_i)$. So this looks like $Ac=y$, where $A$ is a matrix with $a_{ij}=f_j(x_i)$. In MATLAB this system (overdetermined or uniquely determined) can be solved with the backslash operator as

```
c=A\y
```

(If the system is underdetermined, this will still give a result, but you typically want to do something different in the underdetermined case.)

Comment: Thanks but I've got a error like this. >> x=1:4;y=[3.5,4.3,7.2,8];c=polyfit(x,y,d)
Undefined function or variable 'd'.

Comment: Also is this the same between polyfit() and pinv()? why you using the polyfit()?

Comment: @gmotree First, you should not use inv or pinv directly; you should almost always use the backslash operator instead. That said, it is mathematically equivalent to use polyfit vs. setting up the linear system and using backslash. polyfit is optimized for the case of polynomial fitting, and is more convenient (since you don't have to form the matrix yourself).

Comment: @gmotree As for your error, MATLAB told you what was wrong: you need to specify what $d$ is, and I can't do that for you, beyond telling you that it is either 0,1,2, or 3.

Comment: got it, I've choose d=3, but >> y0=c(1)*x0^2+c(2)*x0+c(3)
Undefined function or variable 'x0'. I 've got a error one more.

Comment: @gmotree Again, x0 is whatever evaluation point you want to pick, for instance x0=2.5.

Comment: Thanks Sir I got it. polyfit is more easy.

Comment: but especially, what if x have not continue then is this still work? for example x= 0,3,5,7,8,13 y= 3,7,7,9,100,1

Comment: @gmotree I'm not sure what you mean. If the x's aren't in sequence you can just write out the vector: x=[0 3 5 7 8 13] is fine. 1:4 was just convenient in your original example.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem statement**

Fit the given data set with a sequence of polynomial fits:
$$
 y(x) = a_{0} + a_{1} x + \dots + a_{d} x^{d}
$$
Indicate where we can solve the linear system with the normal equations, and when we must rely exclusively upon the pseudoinverse.

**Linear System**

The linear system for the polynomial with highest order $d$ is
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} a &= y \\
% A
\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
  1 & x_{1} & \cdots & x_{1}^{d} \\
  1 & x_{2} & \cdots & x_{2}^{d} \\
  1 & x_{3} & \cdots & x_{3}^{d} \\
  1 & x_{4} & \cdots & x_{4}^{d} \\
\end{array} \right]
% a
\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
  a_{0} \\
  a_{1} \\
  \vdots \\
  a_{d} \\
\end{array} \right]
%
&=
%
% y
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  y_{1} \\
  y_{2} \\
  y_{3} \\
  y_{4} 
\end{array} \right]
%
\end{align}
$$

**Least squares solution**

The least squares solution is defined as
$$
 a_{LS} = \left\{
a \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1} \colon
\lVert
\mathbf{A} a - y
\rVert_{2}^{2}
\text{ is minimzed}
\right\}
$$

The residual error vector is
$$
 r = \mathbf{A} a - y.
$$
The total error, the quantity minimized, is $r^{2} = r\cdot r$.

**Summary of results**

The total error demonstrates typical behavior. Increasing the order of fit initially reduces the error. Then it plateaus, or may actually increase.

For these data, the cubic fit provides  the best combination of total error and computational cost.

[image: r2]

The amplitudes for each order are collected in the table below.

$$
\begin{array}{clllllll}
 k & a_{0} & a_{1} & a_{2} & a_{3} & a_{4} & a_{5} & a_{6} \\
 0 & 5.75 \\
 1 & 1.65 & \phantom{-}1.64 \\
 2 & 1.65 & \phantom{-}1.64 & \phantom{-}0  \\
 \color{blue}{3} & \color{blue}{9.} & \color{blue}{-10.05} & \phantom{-}\color{blue}{5.25} & \color{blue}{-0.7} \\
 4 & 4.04271 & \phantom{-}0.277692 & -1.97938 & \phantom{-}1.36554 &
   -0.206554 \\
 5 & 2.57594 & \phantom{-}1.38279 & -0.0545302 & -0.868031 &
   \phantom{-}0.545109 & -0.0812778 \\
 6 & 1.89099 & \phantom{-}1.41016 & \phantom{-}0.686033 & -0.172893 &
   -0.615848 & \phantom{-}0.350573 & -0.0490168 \\
\end{array}
$$

**Lower order fits: $d\le 3$**

For $d=0$, the amplitude is given by the mean of the data $a_{0} = \bar{y}$.

For $d=1,2,3$, the normal equations
$$
 \mathbf{A}^{T} \mathbf{A} a = \mathbf{A}^{T} y
$$
can be solved as
$$
  a_{LS} = \left( \mathbf{A}^{T} \mathbf{A} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{A}^{T} y
$$

**Higher order fits: $d\ge 4$**

For $d\ge4$, the product matrix $\mathbf{A}^{T} \mathbf{A}$ is rank deficient and cannpt be inverted. The solution requires the pseudoinverse. The least squares minimizers are the affine space
$$
 a_{LS} = \mathbf{A}^{+}y + \left( \mathbf{I}_{4} - \mathbf{A}^{+} \mathbf{A} \right) z, \quad  z\in \mathbb{R}^{4}
$$

**Sequence of plots**

[image: sequence]